# Dump file error while trying to switch to import to a MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dump file name mydata.dump.sql. Currently using a console of my MYSQL database. To use my data I have tried the source command:

```
source  mydata.dump.sql
```

I am however getting the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRANSACTION' at line 7
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Not sure what' s wrong with that syntax but the dump file was generated by phpmyadmin, so I guessed it was legit.
Here an excerpt from the dump file that shows line 7 :

```
----
-- phpLiteAdmin database dump (http://www.phpliteadmin.org/)
-- phpLiteAdmin version: 1.9.7-dev
-- Exported: 10:39pm on May 20, 2017 (UTC)
-- database file: /home/ubuntu/workspace/finale.db
----
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: This file is not a dump of a MySQL database... it is a dump of a sqlite database.  It's not from php**my**admin, it's clearly from php**lite**admin.

Answer (score 0):

In command line you can use:

```
mysql -u your_username -p database_name < mydata.dump.sql
```

If you are on windows put full path

```
USE your db_name;
SOURCE D:/yourfolder/mydata.dump.sql;
```

Try to replace the name mydata.dump.sql to **mydata_dump.sql**

Some times also for me phpmyadmin got strange errors.
Many people recommend to use  **mysqldump to export** and then mysql ... to import